# Create table report from joining table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a proble with my query, i have to create report but there is no same data.

here is my database https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2bA7StrBpz18tLFgAQh2QV/1

and this is my query example but the result is wrong :

```
    SELECT
    a.IdBukti,c.LineName,a.LineID,a.Tanggal,b.TypeProduksi AS partnamemonthly,a.PartID AS partmonthly,a.QtyPlanning AS qtymonthly,
    d.partnamedaily,d.partiddaily,d.qtydaily
FROM
    trans_ppicbdt_dt a
INNER JOIN ms_part b ON b.PartId = a.PartID
INNER JOIN ms_line c ON c.LineID = a.LineID
INNER JOIN(SELECT
    c.LineName,
    a.LineID,
    a.Tanggal,
    b.TypeProduksi AS partnamedaily,
    a.PartID AS partiddaily,
    a.QtyPlanning AS qtydaily
FROM
    trans_ppich a
INNER JOIN ms_part b ON b.PartId = a.PartID
INNER JOIN ms_line c ON c.LineID = a.LineID
WHERE
    a.Tanggal = '2018-04-11' AND a.DivisiId='DI070' AND a.IdLocation='1'
GROUP BY
    a.LineID,
    a.PartID) d on d.LineID=a.LineID AND d.Tanggal=a.Tanggal
WHERE
    a.Tanggal = '2018-04-11' AND a.DivisiId='DI070' AND a.IdLocation='1'
GROUP BY
    a.LineID,
    a.PartID
```

So i have 2 data, first monthlyplan and second daily plan.
And i want the result like this [image]

Can you help me to create the report in one single query

Comment: This sort of formatting requirement should be handled in your presentation layer, e.g. PHP.

Comment: i have edited my question , have a look

Comment: Could you indent your subqueries and add relevant table info to the page (ie, show only desired fields and how the tables link together).  The data dump is nice, but I'd rather see a chart showing how the tables are linked.

Comment: @TimMorton i dont understand what you mean, 2 table with different data. Only same LineID

Comment: What I'm asking for is to supply only the information that is needed, in a way that shows how they are linked.  There are three tables, but how do they relate to each other?  What are the foreign keys?

Comment: Even though I'm not seeing the relationships between the tables, I'd venture a guess that since you're using inner joins between 3 tables, you're probably limiting the result set more than you'd like.  You probably have one table that you want to have the other two match up with, which would most likely call for a left join.  But until I get a handle on what the fields are and how they relate to each other, I can't really help much.

Comment: @TimMorton in my case. so, both of them have a same LineID. but the partid dan QtyPlanning is different.

Comment: I’m going to have to come back to this later, but am I correct in thinking that you want to iterate through lineids and add matching daily and monthly records if they exist. If so which tables are which? Their naming does not help me understand. (What’s a trans_ppicbdt_dt?)

Comment: @TimMorton trans_ppicbdt_dt is monthly plan , and trans_ppich is daily plan

Comment: Got it. That helps tremendously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier (for me) to figure out how to formulate a query if I can see the relations in a glance.  Here's how Yours would look:

```
(monthly)                                  (daily)
trans_ppicbdt_dt          ms_line          trans_ppich 
----------------          -----------      --------------  
IdUnik (primary)    ----> LineID <----     IdBukti (FK)*
LineID ------------/                  \--- LineID
```

There are some problems with your structure that need to be fixed at the earliest opportunity:

1. `ms_line` needs a primary key.  <strike>`lineID` should work if it is unique.</strike> (no such luck, it is not unique)
2. `trans_ppich` needs a primary key.  `IdBukti` is a foreign key to yet another table.
3. There needs to be an index on `lineID` in all tables.
4. Tables need to be normalized.  You shouldn't have to repeat data over several lines.

Nevertheless, we can still get to where you want to go.  Now that I can see the relation, the query is really rather simple in theory, but I don't have all the required tables and fields:

```
SELECT DISTINCT line.LineName, 
       monthly.{unknown field} as monthlyPartName, 
       monthly.PartID as monthlyPartID, 
       monthly.{unknown field} as monthlyProcess,
       monthly.{unknown field} as monthlyQty,
       daily.{unknown field} as dailyPartName,
       daily.PartID as dailyPartID,
       daily.{unknown field} as dailyQty,
       {unknown table}.{unknown field} as remarks
FROM  ms_line as line
    LEFT JOIN trans_ppicbdt_dt AS monthly ON line.lineID=monthly.lineID
    LEFT JOIN trans_ppich AS daily ON line.lineID=daily.lineID
WHERE 
       {your where clause to filter results}
```

The way this works is it iterates through the (distinct) line items, and looks for a match in the monthly table (`left join monthly`).  If there is a match, it adds the values.  If there isn't a match, it simply adds `null` for values.  Then it does the same for the daily table:  if there is a match, it adds the values, otherwise it simply gives `null` for all daily values.

This will fall apart, however, if lineID is duplicated in rows of the monthly and daily tables.

I don't know where the remarks come from, so that is left as an exercise for you. :)

Comment: with your query  it give me 4 rows, actually in my expected results only 2 rows, like my picture above. Because there are 2 coloumn in my report. first monthly report and second is daily report.

Comment: Ah, that's because `lineName` is not a primary (nor even unique) key, now that I take another look at it.  This query expects there to be only one `lineName` per row in `ms_line`.  You could throw a `DISTINCT` in front of `line.linename`, and this query will *probably* work.  However, I have my doubts that your database is normalized since the foreign key in the other two tables does not refer to a unique key.  I would suggest reading up on database normalization; a properly normalized database is far easier to work with than one that is not.

Comment: ignore about foreign key or relationship table. there is no relation. 2 tables , trans_ppicbdt and trans_ppich is different. If the two tables have the same lineID then the two become one complete data. as an example. Suppose table A has one data and has lineID = 1, then in table B has 3 data that all have LineId = 1. then the two tables A and B into a single report like my picture above. Do you understand now?

Comment: and so table B would have to be aggregated... yeah, that makes things a little more complicated.  So instead of simply left joining the table, you'll need to left join a subquery that gets the aggregated data.  Same idea, just a couple extra steps.  I may take one more shot at this, but I'm going to use the terms in result and leave the translation up to you.  The field and table names confuse me...

Comment: upon further reflection, nope, not the same thing.  I have no clue what ties 'MCM-507' with 'MCM-612' but does not tie it to 'MCM-638 BTK PRG'.  Obviously my simple chart showing relationships was way off the mark.  If you want to solve the problem, you need to chart out the relationships between the table and add that to your post.  Without that, there's just not enough to go on.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean. I've explained it for you. trans_ppicbdt_dt is a (monthly plan) in report and trans_ppich is a (daily plan) in report picture that i have sent. so i want to create report with two tables. and two tables with same LineID. trans_ppicbdt(monthly plan) two data and trans_ppich(daily plan) has two. And all of them different partID. I want both tables to be report like my picture.

Comment: From your example output and convoluted query, I assumed that each line of the report had something in common, ie, MCM-612 and MCM-507 have some reason for being on the same line.In looking at your data, I find no relation between them.  If there is no particular reason that they are on the same lines, then just do two queries where lineID='L1001' and use PHP to format your report.